# video_thumbnail is not getting thumbnail from video in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have ListView with list having VideoFile or Video Network Path starting from https or imageFile or Image Network Path.

According to the type of item of list, I will show different widget.

Especially in case that type is video, I need to show thumbnail.

So I have two functions to fetch thumbnail from video url or video storage path.

```
Future<String?> getVideoFileThumbnail(String filePath) async {
  try {
    final thumbnailPath = await VideoThumbnail.thumbnailFile(
      video: filePath,
      imageFormat: ImageFormat.JPEG,
      quality: 100,
    );

    return thumbnailPath;
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
  return null;
}

Future<String?> getVideoUrlThumbnail(String file) async {
  final thumbnailPath = await VideoThumbnail.thumbnailFile(
    video: file,
    imageFormat: ImageFormat.WEBP,
    quality: 100,
    timeMs: 0,
  );
  return thumbnailPath;
}
```

And in case the item is video I run this function with `FutureBuilder`.

```
ListView.separated(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  itemCount: _selectedImageList.length,
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => _removeImageFromList(index),
      child: SizedBox(
        child: Stack(
          clipBehavior: Clip.none,
          children: [
            Container(
              width: 60,
              height: 60,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                  Radius.circular(
                    Sizes.size10,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
              child: _selectedImageList[index].toString().contains("mp4")
                  ? FutureBuilder(
                      future: getVideoFileThumbnail(
                          _selectedImageList[index]),
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.hasData) {
                          return Image.file(
                            File(
                              snapshot.data!,
                            ),
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          );
                        }
                        return Container();
                      },
                    )
                  : Image.file(
                      File(
                        _selectedImageList[index],
                      ),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: -25,
              right: -30,
              child: Image.asset(
                "assets/jpg/close.png",
                width: 80,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
  separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Gaps.h16;
  },
),
```

But this function is not returning thumbnail url.

And keeps snapshot ConnectionState is `waiting`.

Sometimes it works but mostly it is not working.

I check that url starting from http is opened well and video path is correctly input in function..

Please help me.

Comment: Is your video files load from a server? then you have to check for the video file size and/or CORS exceptions.

Comment: @Dananjaya apart from video url, video local path getting from local storage is not get thumbnail either. path is right -> /data/user/0/com.chugnchunon.chungchunon_android/cache/file_picker/20230927_135146.mp4

Comment: Did you try with setting "thumbnailPath" in VideoThumbnail.thumbnailFile. Ex: thumbnailPath: (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path

Comment: @Dananjaya yes but still not working..

Comment: My suggestion is to check on the plugin issue channel. Maybe you can find a solution from this thread - https://github.com/justsoft/video_thumbnail/issues/133